# jquery get value of input

Tags: javascript, jquery

**My php code**

```
  <input style="text-align: center;" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id("nums"); ?>"
            name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name("nums"); ?>" 
            type="text" value="<?php echo absint($instance["nums"]); ?>" size='3' 
    />
```

and **jquery**:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.div1').slick({
            slidesToShow: 3,
            slidesToScroll: 1,
        });
    });
```

How to get value: `slidesToShow = $instance["nums"]`

Thanks

Comment: Make your slidesToShow(3) as global variable and it will work

Comment: You should use `.val()` to get the value of the input. More importantly, what is the relationship between the `<input>` element and `.div1`? Is it a one-to-one relationship? Are there multiple input elements of different `absint($instance["nums"])` declared as their values?

Comment: It's be good if you could post the generated output of your php, pure HTML that is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare your variable as `GLOBAL` , so that it can be accessed across files(in case php and js are on different pages)

```
$GLOBALS['a'] = absint($instance["nums"]);

$(document).ready(function(){
        $('.div1').slick({
            slidesToShow: <?php echo $GLOBALS['a'];?>
            slidesToScroll: 1,
        });
    });
```

Comment: Will only work if the JS is placed on the same page as the PHP. If the JS is external, you cannot load echo PHP into it.

Answer (score 0):

If you're generating the jQuery code from PHP you can just generate the number there:

```
slidesToShow: <?php echo absint($instance["nums"]); ?>,
```

but you're probably not, if you run the jQuery code after the HTML is loaded you could try:

```
slidesToShow: $("#field_id").val(),
```

Where *field_id* is the generated id for the field. If you don't know that (because it's dynamic from the PHP) you either need to set a variable with the field ID, or if you're doing that you can set a global in the PHP:

```
<script language='javascript'>
    var global_instance_nums = <?php echo absint($instance["nums"]); ?>;
</script>
```

and then use later in the javascript:

```
slidesToShow: global_instance_nums,
```